# How to setup project based environment variable for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I do have a MAVEN based java project that requires some environment variables.

So far, I used a `setenv` bash script to setup them and added few other scripts in the project root to call it and do build, test...

The question is how can make this work with IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported yet, please [vote for this feature](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-41050).